# How to align two lines in Tikzcd

Tags: beamer, align, positioning, tikz-cd

I am trying to align two lines either at the head or at the center and I am finding it impossible.

For example, this code generates the following frame

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
  \text{The following lines are not aligned} \arrow{d}
\\
\begin{aligned}
     &  Line 1\\
     &  Line 2 \text{(Not aligned at the beginning!)} 
\end{aligned}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Ideally, this is what I want
[image]

or

[image]

Are these solutions possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Center

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
  \text{The following lines are not aligned} \arrow{d}
\\
\begin{array}{c}
    Line 1\\
    Line 2 \text{(Not aligned at the beginning!)} 
\end{array}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Left aligned

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}
  \text{The following lines are not aligned} \arrow{d}
\\
\begin{array}{l}
    Line 1\\
    Line 2 \text{(Not aligned at the beginning!)} 
\end{array}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]